# googletest: performing additional operation if test fail

Tags: c++, unit-testing, debugging, opencv, googletest

I'd like to be able to save data to disk in case the test fails. Is there any way to do it within the googletest framework?

```
TEST_F(test_similarity,are_similar) {

  ASSERT_GT(1e-10,norm(im0,im1));

  // If test fails save images to disk for comparison:
  imwrite("im0.png",im0);
  imwrite("im1.png",im1);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are the `Test::HasFailure()`, `Test::HasNonfatalFailure()` and `Test::HasFatalFailure()` functions, that return `true` if there was a (fatal/non-fatal) failure. You could use them to check.

```
TEST_F(test_similarity,are_similar) {

  EXPECT_GT(1e-10,norm(im0,im1)); // Note the change to EXPECT

  // If test fails save images to disk for comparison:
  if(HasFailure()) {  // if not in a TEST, use ::testing::Test::HasFailure()
    imwrite("im0.png",im0);
    imwrite("im1.png",im1);
    FAIL(); //We want to fail fatally; use ADD_FAILURE() to fail non-fatally
  }
}
```

See 
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#checking-for-failures-in-the-current-test for details.

Comment: Almost! `ASSERT_GT()` will bailout before the `imwrite()` calls have a chance. Replace with `EXPECT_GT()`, and bailout the test case, using an explicit `FAILURE()` statement.

Comment: True. I changed it in my answer.

Comment: Add the mentioned `FAILURE()` statement also please, to preserve the original test cases behavior.

Comment: I think its ```FAIL()```, added that.