# How to check if the test failed in Google Test TearDown()?

Tags: googletest, teardown

At the end of every "file based integration" test, I want to clear a temp folder of associated files.

If the test fails, I want to leave the files there, so I can review the unexpected output.

**Is there a way in the Google Test TearDown to check if the test has failed?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [googletest: performing additional operation if test fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892841/googletest-performing-additional-operation-if-test-fail)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there a way in the Google Test TearDown to check if the test has failed?

Yes, you can do that be querying [`::testing::Test::HasFailure()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#checking-for-failures-in-the-current-test) in
the test cases of your fixture and using the result to tally failures in a counter member of
the fixture that can be queried in its `TearDown()`. An elementary example:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Fixture : public ::testing::Test {
    virtual void SetUp() {
        fails = 0;
    }

    virtual void TearDown() {
        if (fails > 0) {
            std::cerr << "Fixture::TearDown sees failures" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    unsigned fails;
};

TEST_F(Fixture, foo) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1,0);
    fails += ::testing::Test::HasFailure();
}
TEST_F(Fixture, bar) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1,1);
    fails += ::testing::Test::HasFailure();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And output:

```
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from Fixture
[ RUN      ] Fixture.foo
/home/imk/dev/so/gtest/main.cpp:19: Failure
      Expected: 1
To be equal to: 0
Fixture::TearDown sees failures
[  FAILED  ] Fixture.foo (0 sec)
[ RUN      ] Fixture.bar
[       OK ] Fixture.bar (0 sec)
[----------] 2 tests from Fixture (0.001 sec total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] Fixture.foo

 1 FAILED TEST
```

Comment: Since 'fails' member is set to 0 for each test, can you not just query ::testing::Test::HasFailure() inside of TearDown?

Comment: @VladKeel  Yes its possible to delete the "fail counter" and immediately check for `::testing::Test::HasFailure()` in `TearDown()`

Answer (score 1):

Simplified and updated version of @mike-kinghan's answer.
Still using the [::testing::Test::HasFailure()](https://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#Test::HasFailure) but without the counter (it will always evaluate to 1 since the `HasFailure()` retuens a boolean)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Fixture : public ::testing::Test {
  virtual void SetUp() {}

  virtual void TearDown() {
    if (::testing::Test::HasFailure()) {
      std::cerr << "Fixture::TearDown sees failures" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Fixture::TearDown sees NO failures" << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

TEST_F(Fixture, foo) { EXPECT_EQ(0, 0); }
TEST_F(Fixture, bar) { EXPECT_EQ(1, 0); }
TEST_F(Fixture, car) { EXPECT_EQ(2, 2); }
TEST_F(Fixture, tar) { EXPECT_EQ(3, 0); }
```

Output:
[image]